# Is there a method to check if two curves (non-linear) are identical

Tags: statistics, physics, mathematical-physics, statistical-inference

I have two data sets of pollutant concentration on simultaneous days. I have to check whether these two curves follow similar pattern or not ( there might be some time lag between both) on daily basis. The variation in my curve is not regular and straight inspite shows peak variation at some time and low concentration at other times. I have to examine the existence of consistence based on each day.

How can I explain it mathematically and prove the variation to be statistically significant ?

Could someone suggest /help
Thanks 
Gracy

Comment: Probably at stats.stackexchange.com they could do a better job with this than this site can.

Comment: If you normalize them (make the area beneath them 1), flip one of them and perform convolution, the maximum value on the resultant graph will be a measurement of how similar they are and the position of the maximum will tell you how much one of them is shifted. Do you have any math software? Matlab etc?

Comment: @grdgfgr : I'm guessing that by "flip" you mean just one of the steps in finding the convolution.  I wouldn't use the word "area" in that way when speaking of a function of an integer variable like this; I'd just say normalize to make the sum equal to $1$. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @Michael Hardy No, if you are using the default convolution function, you need to flip one of the inputs before performing convolution. In other words,  you need to Shift&Sum without flipping anything at all. Because otherwise, a peak of 1 would never be observed for asymmetrical curves.

Comment: @grdgfgr : The sort of convolution one can do in a case like this is $(x*y)(t) = \sum_{s=1}^n x(s)y(t+1-s)$. Is that what you have in mind? ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @Michael Hardy No it should not be flipped. $-s$ flips it. $(x\bigstar y)(t) = \sum_k x(k) y(k+t) $

Comment: @grdgfgr : Several times you've used the word "flipped".  Could you say what you mean by that word?

Comment: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/21/Comparison_convolution_correlation.svg/512px-Comparison_convolution_correlation.svg.png This image illustrates it quite clearly. For convolution g is "flipped". If I have g(t) and make it g(-t), I call that "flipped"

Answer (score 1):

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-correlation is what you are looking for.

If you had data points for 2 curves, you'd normalize them (make their sum equal 1) and perform "cross correlation" which is basically convolution without flipping anything.

The maximum value (out of 1) will tell you how similar the two curves are and the position of the peak will tell you how much delay there is between them.

Comment: Thanks for reply I am exploring it. 1) Will my result be affected and different if I have data gaps in the data set?

Comment: Yes it would. I am sure there are very smart ways to handle it but I don't know it off the top of my head. I would interpolate the gaps and then perform cross correlation if the gaps are not very large in size.

Comment: @Gracy https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/7727/how-to-correlate-two-time-series-with-gaps-and-different-time-bases This might be relevant, if you want to implement better methods.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply and providing link. I will go through it. I cant interpolate my data. I will check  that . Thanks